# Add the “iCloud containers” entitlement to your App ID

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, ios-provisioning, app-id

I am trying to fix this issue for hours now. 
I have checked the App ID and confirmed the iCloud containers. 
Also i have entered the same in the app entitlements.

But there is a always a red mark before  "Add the “iCloud containers” entitlement to your App ID". I created the new provisioning profile and removed the expired provision files also. 
This is the first time i am facing this issue.

Is this issue related with the developer certificate signing or something?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having the same problem couple of days ago. Fixed it by doing these steps:

1. Go to your developer account
2. Find the App ID you are working on
3. Click edit.
4. On the iCloud section select the radio button that says "Include CloudKit support (requires Xcode 6)"
   [image]

Worked for me.

Comment: I already set it, still got red flag on xcode 9 without reason

Answer (score 4):

For me everything was just fine. I had to close and reopen xcode. Then go to 'Capabilities'  and Toggle the 'iCloud' i.e OFF and Then ON it again.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by:

1. Turn off iCloud capabilities.
2. Change the app's bundle id.
3. Turn on iCloud capabilities.

Now everything is regenerated afresh, and the error goes away. Of course, now the bundle id is wrong. But now you can go to the member center, delete the old (faulty) app id and any associated provisioning profiles, and change the bundle id back again.

Comment: I've found out why this works. It sets PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the project.pbxproj file.

Comment: @oferei Fascinating and helpful if true! Thank you very much for your work on this.

Comment: Not a solution, this is a shotgun approach.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to add an App ID matching my project's bundle ID, but it still doesn't update the warnings in iCloud.

Then I found that in "General" -> "Signing" it says `Target is ad hoc signed`, and I tapped the `Enable Development Signing` button, then Xcode started to auto manage the App ID etc and everything turned green :]

Comment: Worked for me too, except in Xcode 9 the checkmarks are gray, not green, and originally it said `Target is unsigned`, because I've been signing by scripting the `codesign` command-line tool since before Xcode had this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, under Xcode - General - Signing, the name in the Team field was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Xcode 9.1, I had to choose the Team in Signing section (Target -> General pane). The team was already chosen but I had to choose it again to make the error disappear. It might have to do with developer certificate renewal.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above, in the end all I did was quit Xcode, open it up again, and toggle the iCloud capability off and on again.

Answer (score 0):

Try
 - delete all provisioning profiles
 - go to Xcode->preference->account
 - add your apple id here (makes you easy to download profiles)
 - Click download profiles.

Answer (score 0):

1. I Turned on iCloud
2. Set the Cloud kit Container through the Apple Developer dashboard to the app I needed
3. Rename project bundle Identifier from the Xcode 10 and rename back to the original identifier after all fine
4. Provisional profile got updated